# Index Function in VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba, indexing

Can Someone help me in Converting this code in VBA. 
Is is possible to do it Via the worksheet function.
Sorry I am a Noob and just learning.

```
=INDEX($L$1:$Z$4,4,MATCH(AQ$2,$L$1:$Z$1,0))
```

Comment: look into `worksheet.evaluate`

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following (or using evaluate) but this handles not being found.

```
Sub TEST()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change

Dim indexRange As Range
Set indexRange = ws.Range("$L$1:$Z$4")

Dim matchRange As Range
Set matchRange = ws.Range("$L$1:$Z$1")
Dim searchValue As Variant

searchValue = ws.Range("AQ$2").Value2

Dim result As Variant

On Error GoTo errHand
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(indexRange, 4, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(searchValue, matchRange, 0))

MsgBox result

Exit Sub

errHand:

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Value not found"
End If

End Sub
```

Edit:

Or as per @ScottCraner: Simplify

```
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(indexRange, 4, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(searchValue, matchRange, 0))
```

To

```
result = indexRange.Cells(4,Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(searchValue, matchRange, 0))
```

Comment: Nothing gets by The Craner. I had deleted my comment about their choice of ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

```
MsgBox Evaluate("=INDEX($L$1:$Z$4,4,MATCH(AQ$2,$L$1:$Z$1,0))")
```

---

### More Info:

- MSDN : [Application.Evaluate Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-evaluate-method-excel)

Comment: you will want to use `Worksheets("Sheet2").Evaluate` or it will evaluate the formula on the active sheet.